# Implementing save/load functionality on an HTML page

Tags: html, upload, save

I have an HTML page which is a time sheet so employees can record what sort of things they've done for the day and submit it. The time sheet works great in it's current state and works with an Access DB to save the information. Now, I would like for somebody to halfway fill out a time sheet, save it, load it later in the day, finish filling it out, and then finally submit it.

What are some good practices/methods to accomplish this? I'm wondering if there's anything better than just saving the data into a data table and then loading it back up to the site at the request of a user. This seems like the most obvious solution, but I'm wondering if there's a slightly more clever one.

Comment: The most obvious solution is often the correct one. You *could* save to a file but a database is the ideal solution.

Comment: Agreed. Saving it to the database is the best way to do this. You could save it to a 'temporary' table for example, or to the 'real deal' table but with a flag that says "incomplete". Then some logic on your site that doesn't allow changes to sheets that are marked 'complete' if that's appropriate. But DB is the way to go. Stop using Access DB's though ;-)  Use SQL or MySQL or something

Comment: Alright thanks for the answers. And yeah a shift away from Access would be nice. The project has gotten bigger than originally expected and using something else would be well worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the person will be using the same computer, you could store the data in localStorage instead of having to write it to the server, which might be easier as the data would be stored in the browser. I don't know if this is the best option, but it is an option.